# UICollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize()

Tags: ios, swift

I have already cast Int to `CGFloat`,but the Xcode still tell me this error

```
import UIKit
class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  var numPages = 0
  var nums: CGFloat?

  override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth * (CGFloat)numPages, height: collectionView?.bounds.height)
    // error: Expected ','separator
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you have to create a `CGFloat` using the `Int`, rather than cast it. Like this: `CGFloat(numpages)`.

You'll probably also have compiler trouble with the optional `CGFloat`s, so you'll need to check that the `collectionView` is non-nil, or force-unwrap it if you know it's non-nil.